# Summing up Unique Products

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A problem I have been working on recently requires sums similar to:

$6+5+4+3+2+1$

$3\cdot3+3\cdot2+3\cdot1+2\cdot2+2\cdot1+1\cdot1$

$7\cdot7\cdot7+7\cdot7\cdot6+...+7\cdot7\cdot1+7\cdot6\cdot6+...+2\cdot1\cdot1+1\cdot1\cdot1$

What I want to know is if there is an equation that could calculate these types of sums. I do have a way to do it with a recursive function:

$$S(a,b)=\sum_{i=1}^a{i\cdot S(i,b-1)}$$
*where*
$$S(x,0)=1$$ *for any x*

Going back to the previous examples:

$S(6,1)=6+5+4+3+2+1$

$S(3,2)=3\cdot3+3\cdot2+3\cdot1+2\cdot2+2\cdot1+1\cdot1$

However using this can be a little tedious at times, even with a computer.

EDIT:

If it helps any, what I am using this function for is for finding:

$$a! \cdot S(a,b)$$

Comment: All the methods so far seem to take time proportional to $a$ or higher.  I just want to point out that for small $b$ these can be computed quite efficiently regardless of how large $a$ is.  Just wondering whether this would help for your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers appear to be Stirling's numbers 2nd kind.
See the matrix of S[r,c] , look at the columns:

```
   1    1     1      1       1        1
   3    7    15     31      63      127
   6   25    90    301     966     3025
  10   65   350   1701    7770    34105
  15  140  1050   6951   42525   246730
  21  266  2646  22827  179487  1323652
```

See the matrix of Stirling numbers 2nd kind; look at the diagonals:

```
  1    .    .     .     .    .
  1    1    .     .     .    .
  1    3    1     .     .    .
  1    7    6     1     .    .
  1   15   25    10     1    .
  1   31   90    65    15    1
  1   63  301   350   140   21
  1  127  966  1701  1050  266
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to find a very satisfying result so far, maybe someone else can help. Note that $$S[a,1]=\frac{1}{2}a(a+1)$$

From the recursion formula, we can find the next few sums. Plugging this into Mathematica, shows we find a sequence of the form $$ S[a,b] = \sum_{i=1}^{a} \frac{(-1)^i i^{a+b}}{i!(a-i)!} $$

This can also be simplified to $$ S[a,b] =-\left(x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{a+b-1} \frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} (-1)^{i+1} x^{i+1} {a-1 \choose i} \bigg|_{x=1} $$

Using the binomial expansion, we find

$$ S[a,b] =-\frac{(-1)^{a-1}}{(a-1)!} \left(x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{a+b-1} x(1-x)^{a-1} \bigg|_{x=1} $$

which in turn can be simplified to

$$ S[a,b] = \frac{1}{(a-1)!} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^{a+b-1}\left(e^t(e^t-1)^{a-1}\right) \bigg|_{t=0} $$

I believe this formula is correct, but I do not have a proof of the Mathematica step yet. You could try to prove it by induction.

Checking this formula for $$S[2,1] = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (e^t(e^t-1)) \bigg|_{t=0} = \left(e^t(e^t-1) + 3e^{2t}\right)\bigg|_{t=0} = 3 $$

It also works for $S[3,2]$, for example, but it quickly becomes cumbersome to check.